# Calculating Laurent expansion for $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$

Tags: power-series, laurent-series

I don't have any idea where should I start for calculating Laurent expansion for the following function :

$$\frac{1}{1-z^2}$$

The thing that I've got in my notes is finding a form like the power series and then Laurent expansion can be written by putting all the $n$ inside the summation and you are OK.

I know the poles are $1,-1$ also. and the expansion should be calculated around the pole $z=1$.

Comment: ...and so you want a Laurent expansion around... *what*?

Comment: @DonAntonio around the poles i believe :-?

Comment: Use $$\frac1z=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n(z-1)^n$$

Comment: @clathratus it's a way hard task to do applying power series summation to the $\frac{1}{1-z^2}$ on the z=1 pole :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1+z}+\frac1{1-z}\right)$$

So, for example, around the simple pole $\;z=-1\;$ :

$$\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{1+z}-\frac12\cdot\frac1{-2+1+z}=\frac12\cdot\frac1{1+z}+\frac14\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{1+z}2}$$

and thus for $\;\left|\frac{1+z}2\right|<1\iff|1+z|<2\;$ , we get the Laurent expansion of the function around $\;z=-1\;$ :

$$\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac1{2(1+z)}+\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1+z)^n}{2^n}$$

Now you try the expansion around $\;z=1\;$ ...

Comment: I've got the very similar power series, and i'm suspect if it's right? 

for the pole z=1:
$\frac{1}{1-z^2} = \frac{1}{2(1-z)} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1-z)^n}{2^n}$

Comment: i've got serious problem with this, cause the note says it should be |z-1|>2 for this pole and i don't have any clue why?

Comment: Too bad you didn't say in your question that the requirement was that $\;|z-1|>2\;$ ...this is a **huge** difference! Maybe you should post a new question with this so-important piece of information.

Comment: My teacher is so old, he didn't said it's a hypothesis and said it after writing power series and actually  took $|z-1|>2$ from power series. my problem actually was that exactly.